# Call overloaded generic method from generic method

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

My question is: Why is `AddData(string data)` never called? When I call `ds.Add("Some text")` then the type of `data` parameter is known at compilation time thus the overloaded implementation of `Add` should call `AddData(string)` method (or this is what I was hoped for)

The output is

```
Ignore data of type System.String
Ignore data of type System.Double
```

```cs
using System;

namespace GenericCall
{
    interface IDataStore
    {
        void Add<T>(T data);
    }

    class MyDataStore : IDataStore
    {
        public void Add<T>(T data)
        {
            AddData(data);
        }

        private void AddData<T>(T data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Ignore data of type {data.GetType()}");
        }

        private void AddData(string data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Accept string data");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyDataStore ds = new MyDataStore();
            ds.Add("Some text");
            ds.Add(3.14);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You basically want `Add` to call one of two different methods depending on the parameter type. Short answer - the compiler doesn't do what you wish it did. It chooses the best match it can (`AddData<T>`) at compile time and _always_ calls it. It does this basically for simplicity - since it can't know at compile time whether it will be called with a `string` or `int` or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overload resolution happens at compile time for your code.

At compile time, the compiler has no knowledge of what `T` actually is, so this call:

```
public void Add<T>(T data)
{
    AddData(data); <------
}
```

can *only* be resolved to the generic `AddData`, according to the [rules of overload resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#overload-resolution).

One way to make overload resolution happen at runtime is to make the public `Add` accept a `dynamic` parameter:

```
// you should change the interface declaration also!
public void Add(dynamic data)
{
    AddData(data);
}
```

This will produce the output:

```
Accept string data
Ignore data of type System.Double
```

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks a lot! I started to think about manual reflection but using `dynamic` does for me. But just to make sure. When I call `Add("text")` and `Add(1.23)` the compiler generates only one method `Add`, right? Otherwise it could fit `AddData` better and call appropriate version.

Comment: @user2146414 Yes, there is only one `Add` method in IL. [Learn more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic). That said, `dynamic` should be used _sparingly_. My example was only meant to show you what overload resolution at runtime looks like. I'm not sure whether this is an appropriate use of dynamic without know more of your situation. I suggest you read [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/256566/when-to-not-use-dynamic-in-c) first.