# Calling non-generic method from generic method in C#

Tags: c#, generics

This is similar to this question [Call overloaded generic method from generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62114504/call-overloaded-generic-method-from-generic-method) but it's not the same: in that case, the method returned `void`, while I need to return the generic type `T`, so the proposed solution does not work.

I'm implementing a tuple-like class which has generic parameters and accessors for these parameters:

```
public class MyClass<T1, T2>
{
    private readonly T1 _item1;
    private readonly T2 _item2;

    public MyClass(T1 item1, T2 item2)
    {
        _item1 = item1;
        _item2 = item2;
    }

    public T1 GetItem(T1 _) => _item1;

    public T2 GetItem(T2 _) => _item2;

    private T GetItem<T>(T x)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
        // return x;
    }

    public T Get<T>()
    {
        return GetItem(default(T));
    }
}
```

I would like to use this class like this:

```
var obj = new MyClass<int, string>(1, "hello");
var a = obj.Get<int>();
var b = obj.Get<string>();
```

But if I try this, the Generic `T GetItem<T>(T x)` is always called (the exception is thrown), and not the non-generic implementations.

If I try to access the `GetItem` method directly, it works as intended:

```
var obj = new MyClass<int, string>(1, "hello");
var q = obj.GetItem(default(int));
var w = obj.GetItem(default(string));
```

`q` and `w` contain `1` and `hello` as expected.

Is there a way for me to use this class as I want (using `obj.Get<T>`)? I want to avoid `Item1` `Item2` `Item3` getters.

Comment: Can you show how you have _attempted_ to use the answer from that post?

Comment: your code is pretty flawed. You have two identical methods `GetItem`, which return different things depending on the parameter whose sole purpoise is to distinguish betwen the calls. You should just use two different names for that, e.g. `GetItem1` and `GetItem2`.

Comment: Overload resolution is done at compile-time, not at runtime. When the compiler compiled the `Get<T>` method, it had to decide, there and then, which overload of `GetItem` it was going to call. Of course, at that point, the compiler doesn't know what `T` is going to be: it could be `string` or `int` or anything else. So it had to pick the generic `GetItem<T>` overload

Comment: You're going to be in a world of pain when you want a tuple with two items with the same type...

Comment: @Sweeper if I use the dynamic with generics, then I always have to pass the data parameter as argument (my second example), or the generic T is called (my first example). If I don't use generics, then...well, I can't use generics which defeats the purpose. `dynamic` has no effects either way, in this case. @Matthew two items with the same type break business rules. UB would be acceptable in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if I try this, the Generic `T GetItem<T>(T x)` is always called (the exception is thrown), and not the non-generic implementations.

That's because overload resolution happens at compile-time, and at compile-time, the concrete type of `T` is unknown.

> Is there a way for me to use this class as I want (using `obj.Get<T>`)?

Using plain old dynamic type checking, sure:

```
public class MyClass<T1, T2>
{
    private readonly T1 _item1;
    private readonly T2 _item2;

    public MyClass(T1 item1, T2 item2)
    {
        _item1 = item1;
        _item2 = item2;
    }

    public T Get<T>()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(T1))
        {
            return (T)(object)_item1;
        } 
        
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(T2))
        {
            return (T)(object)_item2;
        }
        
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

The advantage of this solution is that the behavior of the edge cases (T1 == T2, or T matches neither T1 nor T2) is properly defined and easy to see.

---

Alternatively, you *can* use the `dynamic` "hack" used in the question you linked to, you just need to cast the result to `T`: `return (T)GetItem((dynamic)default(T));`, here's a [working fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EjjOmU).

But this is just plain ugly, please don't do that. Compare the fiddle with the version above and try to judge honestly which one is easier to read, easier to understand, and, thus, easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

## Tests

```
var instance = new MyClass<string, int>("hello", 1);
Console.WriteLine(instance.GetItem("hi"));
Console.WriteLine(instance.GetItem(2));
// returns "hello"
Console.WriteLine(instance.Get<string>());
// returns "1"
Console.WriteLine(instance.Get<int>());
// throws with details
Console.WriteLine(instance.Get<object>());
```

## Implementation

```
public T Get<T>()
{
    var parentType = typeof(MyClass<T1, T2>);
    var method = parentType.GetMethod(nameof(GetItem), new[] { typeof(T) });
    if (method == null)
        throw new NotImplementedException(
            $"No implementation for {nameof(GetItem)} with parameter type {typeof(T).FullName}");

    var result = (T)method.Invoke(this, new object[] { default(T) });
    return result;
}
```

This version uses reflection. If you need more performance you should go for compiled expressions, but that is harder to maintain

Comment: yeah, I wouldn't like to call reflection on every Get. Do you have any suggestions where I could read about compiled expressions?

Comment: @fnzr google "c# compiled expression" there are lots of articles on it. The syntax is pretty confusing unless you read up on it. these days reflection is not that slow and it is easy to understand, so unless your use case is very performance critical i would not go that route

Answer (score 0):

What if you had the same data-type for the two items?

```
var obj = new MyClass<int, int>(1, 2);
```

what should `GetItem` return here? Obviously there's no valid answer to this.

Anyway providing a parameter only to distinguish which method to call is pretty odd. Actually your `GetItem<T>`-method shouldn't be generic at all. Just use two different methods:

```
T1 GetItem1() => _item1;
T2 GetItem2() => _item2;
```

or use auto-properties to get rid of the backing-fields:

```
public class MyClass<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 Item1 { get; }
    public T2 Item2 { get; }

    public MyClass(T1 item1, T2 item2)
    {
        Item1 = item1;
        Item2 = item2;
    }
```